# Segmentation fault and printf warinings

Tags: c, linux, struct, segmentation-fault, format-specifiers

My program has some warnings, and then it crashes. It seems likely that the crash is related to the warnings, but I don't understand them. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct student {
    char name[100];
    int id;
    char *department;
    struct result {
        float gpa;
        char grade;
    } res;
};

int main(void) {
    struct student W[] = {{"Saud Farooqui",137,"Electronics",{3.05,'A'}},
          {"Talha Farooqui",129,"Civil",{3.5,'A'}}};

    printf("First student data is\n%s\t%d\t%s\t%f\t%c",W[0].name,W[0].id,
         W[0].department,W[1].res.gpa,W[0].res.grade);

    printf("\nSecond student data is\n%s\t%d\t%s\t%f\t%c",W[1].name,W[1].id,
         W[1].res.gpa,W[1].res.grade);
}
```

The compiler printed these warnings about the format specifiers in the second `printf`:

```
foo.c:24:10: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 4 has type 'double' [-Wformat=]
          W[1].res.gpa,W[1].res.grade);
          ^
foo.c:24:10: warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 5 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
foo.c:24:10: warning: format '%c' expects a matching 'int' argument [-Wformat=]
```

When I tried to launch the program, the first `printf` printed a line, but the second one failed:

```
 Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What is wrong with it? How do I fix the warnings and the crash?

Comment: what isn't clear in the warning messages? and don't you think the segfault is somehow related to your ignoring the warnings? warnings are useful you know. You're taking it the wrong way round. First fix the warnings, and maybe your code will run, just like that.

Comment: I've tried to rearrange the information a bit, and now I think the question is both more readable and a reasonably good question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing argument for `department`. It is obvious, when you compile
it with warnings turned on (`-Wall`):

```
a.c:21:7: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 4 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat=]
       W[1].name, W[1].id,  W[1].res.gpa, W[1].res.grade);
       ^
a.c:21:7: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 5 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
a.c:21:7: warning: format ‘%c’ expects a matching ‘int’ argument [-Wformat=]
```

Also, your first `printf` prints `W[1].res` which is probably supposed to be `W[0].res`.

Fixed version:

```
struct student W[] = {{"Saud Farooqui",137,"Electronics",{3.05,'A'}},
  {"Talha Farooqui",129,"Civil",{3.5,'A'}}};

printf("First student data is\n%s\t%d\t%s\t%f\t%c",
    W[0].name, W[0].id, W[0].department, W[0].res.gpa, W[0].res.grade);

printf("\nSecond student data is\n%s\t%d\t%s\t%f\t%c",
    W[1].name, W[1].id, W[1].department, W[1].res.gpa, W[1].res.grade);
```

So the segmentation fault is due to the attempt to interpret `W[1].res.gpa` as a pointer to a string (corresponding to the `%s` format specifier), i.e. `const char *`.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `W[1].department`?

Comment: And although it doesn't cause a segmentation violation, shouldn't `W[1].res` in the first `printf` be `W[0].res`? And wouldn't the whole thing be better as a loop instead?

Comment: Are you sure the OP didn't mean `W[1].res`?

Comment: @msw, yes, because _the first student_ is under the first index, i.e. `0`

Comment: So what is the reason of downvotes? Please write something so that I can fix it?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, do you really mean that the message like _you should fix the warnings first_ has indeed fixed his problem, or maybe helped to understand the reason of segfault? Also, does the SO policy prohibits answering trivial questions? There are plenty of trivial questions and trivial answers in SO. All worth of hundreds of upvotes. So what's wrong with my answer? If you've got something against the question itself, then vote to close it.

Comment: voted to close, I forgot to do it. I agree that most questions contain some triviality in it, but this question could be solely solved by reading the warnings, but sometimes that's complicated, so it's worth an answer. Here the fixes are quite simple, it's almost a typo. Stay away of sunday questions, downvoted multiple times, with "student" in it, and trivial. Anyway, you got 2 upvotes so it's well balanced, you're getting away with it.